# Error `cannot add bindings to a locked environment` when working with S3 class

Tags: r, r-package

I'm developing a R package. Here's my S3 class and related functions.

```
# Define a generic function for getting suggestions
  get_suggestion <- function(x, language) {
  # Define a new S3 class for misspelled words
  setClass("misspelled_words", representation(words="character"))
  UseMethod("get_suggestion")
}

# Define a method for character vectors
get_suggestion.character <- function(misspelled_words, language) {
  suggestions <- hunspell::hunspell_suggest(misspelled_words, dict = dictionary(language))
  message(paste0("Getting suggestions using ", language, " dictionary."))
  return(suggestions)
}

# Define a method for misspelled_words objects
get_suggestion.misspelled_words <- function(misspelled_words, language) {
  suggestions <- hunspell::hunspell_suggest(misspelled_words@words, dict = dictionary(language))
  message(paste0("Getting suggestions using ", language, " dictionary."))
  return(suggestions)
}


# Define a method for lists of misspelled_words objects(using parallel processing)
get_suggestion.list <- function(misspelled_words, language) {
  cl <- parallel::makeCluster(parallel::detectCores()-1)
  doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)
  suggestions <- foreach::foreach(mw = misspelled_words, .combine = c) %dopar% {
    hunspell::hunspell_suggest(mw, language)
  }
  parallel::stopCluster(cl)
  return(suggestions)
}
```

I had no errors when running this function on testing examples. But when I put these functions into my package, I loaded my package, and run testing example, I encountered `Error in assign(mname, def, where) :  cannot add bindings to a locked environment`

I thought about unlocking the environment, but it seems to be very dangerous. Are there ways to solve this error?

Comment: I thin the representation function is for S4 functions. Here’s what the `methods` help page says: “  The representation() function is no longer useful, since the arguments slots and contains to setClass are now recommended.”

Comment: you are right! I deleted the representation() arguments and it's still giving me the same error:(